# Deploying wcf with silverlight application?

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I am trying to deploy a Silverlight application on a remote server. I've copied over the files within App.Web which includes the .svc file. I created a virtual directory within IIS 6.0 and am able to successfully host the silverlight portion.

BUT... now I am getting an error:

> The type 'ServiceGateway', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive could not be found.

I've tried restarting IIS, verified that the ISAPI mapping for .svc extension is showing in IIS.

It seems to me that the service is not getting started.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a type sounds like it either wasn't compiled properly or the reference doesn't exist on the server.  What version of .NET is installed on the server?  It should be at least 3.0.

Comment: compilation was the culprit. Doing a clean and rebuild did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the service isn't getting started because you're missing the ServiceGateway type. You may be missing the entire assembly it's meant to be in.

Comment: I don't know how that could be the case if the VS2008 Publish feature should have taken care of that

Comment: Please take a look and see if the bin directory is present, with the correct assembly in it, and check if the assembly has the class in it.